# Best database design to find relationships between two persons

Tags: sql, database-design, relationship

I want to find relationships between two persons using a database. For example, I have a database like this:

```
Person:             
Id| Name
1 | Edvard            
2 | Ivan            
3 | Molly
4 | Julian
5 | Emily
6 | Katarina

Relationship:
Id| Type
1 | Parent
2 | Husband\Wife
3 | ex-Husband\ex-Wife

Relationships:
Id| Person_1_Id | Person_2_Id | Relation_Id
1 | 1           | 3           | 2
2 | 3           | 4           | 3 
3 | 3           | 2           | 1
4 | 4           | 2           | 1 
5 | 1           | 6           | 3
6 | 1           | 5           | 1 
7 | 6           | 5           | 1
```

What the best way to find what relationship between Person-2 and Person-5? This example is not large enough, but what if there were 5 families or 10000. I think, if there are too many families, then it is necessary to introduce the concept of depth.  Maybe it will be better to change the database design? Is this possible to make it like trees or graphs? Some ideas on how to solve this problem differently?

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you get above a handful of nodes and a few relationships between them, this becomes a very complex problem: there are whole branches of maths based around this type of challenge and how long it takes to compute a result.

For any non-trivial set of nodes/relationships you are going to need to look at deploying a graph database e.g. [Neo4j](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-database/)